# JSMPEG extract audio from decoded stream

Tags: streaming, rtsp, decoding, jsmpeg

I'm using Jsmpeg in a NextJS App and a NodeJS server, and everything is working just fine. I have build a relatively complex app, but I need a feature and I don't know if it's possible.

I want to create a decibelmeter for the decoded streams. I know that Jsmepg decodes audio and video separately, but I'm not finding the way to extract the audio and process it, and since the stream is being showed in a canvas element, theres no audio to extract from it. I've been looking everywhere a way to do this, but I'm not being successful.

To do the app I've been following the JSMPEG documentation:
https://github.com/phoboslab/jsmpeg